# Salmon with green back

Tags: food-safety, salmon

I've just found some deep frozen salmon in my freezer but I'm unsure if it's still eatable though the package says it still should. The case is that the salmon is still pink as it should be but it's back where the back bone should be, it's green/grayish. Is the fish still alright?

Answer (score 7):

If you bought your salmon frozen, and kept it frozen this entire time then it is safe to eat.

Foods actually remain safe indefinitely when stored below freezing. You should be aware that safe does not necessarily mean palatable. As food ages, even when frozen, it degrades in quality via oxidation and other chemical processes. This degradation in quality will definitely affect the taste, and even the nutritional value to a degree.

For salmon, it will taste best within 7 to 9 months.

Source: http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18246

Comment: Thanks very helpful, that site will also be good for later use! I'm preparing my salmon ^^ let's see how it tastes =P

Comment: While foods may be safe for a very long time, they cease to be good eats after 4-6 months (depending on packaging).  Once the moisture is coerced out of the food by the hygroscopic, colder air surrounding it, the texture changes (and eventually starts to taste like shoe leather).

Comment: Now if you're a cheap bastard like I am, you can cheat a bit with shoe-leathered-freezer-burnt-foods: they can be ground into other things.  Not exactly good eats, but safe and frugal (and you won't often notice a flavour change). They can sometimes be added to soup stocks too.